# Can a Jew buy something from a vending machine that was not sold during Pesach?

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven, business

The scenario:

The vending machine is physically located in a Jewish-owned business. A non-Jewish vendor owns the physical machine and is responsible for stocking the chametz cookies in the machine. The vendor comes once per week, and empties the money, and restocks the machine with products that he owns. Every month, he gives the Jewish owner a percentage of the sales. The vendor also pays the Jew a space rental fee for allowing him to keep the vending machine there.

My question - Can a Jewish employee purchase chametz from this machine after Pesach? Is the Jewish business owner considered owning chametz during Pesach by the fact that he gets a percentage of sales, in general, or is the fact that the currently purchased product not having ben sold during Pesach exempt from this prohibition? Also, is the usage fee an implication of the Jew owning the machine and its contents?

Comment: Why not? The chametz always belonged to the goy...

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @EzraHoerster here. The Jew appears to be an Aris, not an owner. As a "sharecropper" he gets a percentage of the proceeds but has no direct ownership in the implements and goods  of the business

Comment: This is all assuming that no goods were sold during Pesach. If goods were sold, there could be a problem because the hametz is forbidden for benefit - and the shopkeeper gets a percentage.

Comment: @Epicentre Just want to verify that you understand the scenario, clearly, since you said "no goods were sold". The specific item you are buying from the machine was obviously not sold. Are you sure that the fact that any order item was sold from the nmachine would disqualify use of the 1 item you are buying now. If so, why is that?

Comment: If goods were sold (even though obviously not this specific item), then there is potential benefit from _all_ the hametz in the machine. The question then arises if _potential_ benefit from all the hametz in the machine disqualifies the hametz after Pesach.